# popen returns error when executing python script containing logging

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I have 2 python scripts where 1 is using subprocess to execute the other, see below:

main.py

```
import subprocess

command = ['python', 'logging_test.py']
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = proc1.communicate()

print('Output returned from command: {}'.format(out))
print('Error returned from command: {}'.format(err))
```

logging_test.py

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('log')
logger.info('hello')
```

When running main.py I get this as the output:

```
Output returned from command:
Error returned from command: INFO:log:hello
```

I would expect for the log message to be returned by stdout, not stderr... Does anyone know why it is getting returned as an error?

Comment: Standard error is for diagnostics as well as error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basicConfig`, among other things, [provides a `StreamHandler` for the root logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig). By default, a [new `StreamHandler` writes to standard error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler).

Comment: Ahhh okay, thanks!  setting stream=sys.stdout in basicConfig or StreamHandler resolves this for me.